# Log statement is repeating in log files

Tags: log4j

I have to log in different-2 file. So I have created two appender. One for basic log which would log little bit information.
Second appender will be dynamic and depending on the one parameter log file name will be different. Both scenario are working fine.
Now just found the log statement are getting added.
Means first time it write once, second time tow lines and third time three and so on..  My program runs on every 20 seconds. If I close the program and run again it will not repeat but if continuous runs every 20 second then it start repeat log. 
I have used log4j.Create to logger and adding appender in this. Every thing I am doing by code. Not using any log file. Below is one of them.

```
static Logger loggerCustom = Logger.getLogger("CustomLog");
PatternLayout plt = new PatternLayout();
            plt.setConversionPattern("%-7p %d [%t] %c %x - %m%n");
            fh = new FileAppender(plt, "logs\\" + strDate + "\\CustomLog.log");
            loggerCustom.addAppender(fh);
            loggerCustom.setAdditivity(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Dear All above issue has been resolve by adding below line before appending appender.

```
.removeAllAppenders()
```